# Global Mapper Opening Error

Tags: global-mapper

I am having a problem when I am opening Global Mapper workspace that I had already created and saved it. Evey time I try to open it an error appear and nothing opens on the screen. Is there a way to open this .gmw file.

Comment: What is the error? can you post the screenshot of it?

Comment: what version of global mapper do you use?

Comment: Did you mean to put arcgis and arcmap tags on this? It sounds like only GlobalMapper is involved.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the source data files have been moved. Open the .gmw file in a text editor and check the path of the map file located within it by searching for IMPORT FILENAME=
If you still can't figure it out, contact Blue Marble's excellent support.